How to opt-out of all experiments?
Just the other day I was reading
Upcoming changes to sign-up flow on the Stack Exchange network
and realized that some interactions I might be having with the software might be different than those other users are having, which might cause confusion when discussing them.
So how can I opt out, like of Variations in Chrome, or at least see a list, of the current experiments I am participating in, so I can be more aware if what I am seeing might be something others are seeing?
In fact it seems I would need a complete list of all experiments, with boxes checked next to the ones I am in, so I could also tell if what others are seeing might be different than what I am seeing... i.e., both ways.

Here we see the confusion caused: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431112/how-to-tell-if-a-tag-wiki-article-exists-before-clicking-its-link-within-the-edi?noredirect=1#comment1003331_431112
